# Server doesn't forward message to all in the chat

Tags: java, sockets

i am trying to create a simple chat app using java sockets, the server is threaded, when a client connects its socket is added to an ArrayList, so that i can send to all in that list.

the problem is when 3 clients are connected, the for loop that sends doesn't work properly, for ex : client 0 sends to both 1 and 2 but client 2 doesn't send to anyone :(

The server and the ClientHandler :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainServer {

    private static int portnumber = 6968;
    static ArrayList <ClientHandler> allClients = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // init
        // server works by default on localhost
        ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(portnumber);
        int clientNo = 0;
    
        System.out.println("server is running on port : " + portnumber);

        while (true) {

          // creating a socket for each connection
          Socket clientsocket = null;

          try {
             // receiving incoming requests from users/clients
            clientsocket = serversocket.accept();

            // input and output from client
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientsocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientsocket.getInputStream()));

            // create a threads
            ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(clientsocket, "Client#" + clientNo, in, out);
        
            // adding to the clientList
            allClients.add(ch);

            System.out.println(ch.clientName + " has joined");
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(ch);
            
            clientThread.start();

            // decrease when user leaves
            clientNo++;
           
          } catch (Exception e) {
            clientsocket.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);

            //out.close();
            //in.close();
            //clientSocket.close();
            //serverSocket.close();
          }
        }
    }
}


// handle client requests
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable{

  public String clientName;
  public Socket clientsocket = null;
  public boolean active = false;
  private BufferedReader inp;
  private PrintWriter out;
  private final String EXIT_STR = "exit";
  public Scanner clientSc = new Scanner(System.in);

  public ClientHandler(Socket socket, String name, BufferedReader inp, PrintWriter out) {
    this.clientsocket = socket;
    this.clientName = name;
    this.inp = inp;
    this.out = out;

    // active when the thread is created
    this.active = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {

    // getting the output temp
    String recivedMsg = "";
    
    while (true) {
      try {
        recivedMsg = inp.readLine();

        System.out.println(recivedMsg);

        // check for ctrl+C
        if (recivedMsg.equals(this.EXIT_STR)){

          // send to all
          System.out.println(this.clientName + " exits");

          // close the connection and break
          this.active = false;
          this.clientsocket.close();

          // bye
          break;
        }

        // send to all except me
        for (ClientHandler client : MainServer.allClients){

          if (!client.clientName.equals(this.clientName)){
            client.out.println(this.clientName + ":" + recivedMsg);
            client.out.flush();
            break;
          }
        }
        
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    try {
      // clean
      this.clientsocket.close();
      this.inp.close();
      this.out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The client :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
  private String hostName; 
  private int portNumber;

  // set connction and server
  public PrintWriter out = null;
  public BufferedReader in = null; 
  public Socket clientSocket = null;

  Client(String hostName, int port) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
    this.portNumber = port;

    // setting the connction
    this.setConnection();
  }

  private void setConnection () {

    try {
      this.clientSocket = new Socket(this.hostName, this.portNumber);
      this.out = new PrintWriter(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }

 }

  public void sendMessageToServer(String msg) {
    //System.out.println("The msg is : " + msg);
    out.println(msg);
  }

  public String readMessage() {
    String outputMsg = "";
    try {
      outputMsg =  in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputMsg;
  }


  // shit cleaning
  public void closeSession(){

    try {
      this.out.close();
      this.in.close();
      this.clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Session has been terminated!");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    // init    
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 6968;

    Client newClient = new Client(host, port);

    // // send a message 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    Thread sendMsg = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (true) {

          try {

            String userInput = sc.nextLine();
            newClient.sendMessageToServer(userInput);

            if (userInput.equals("exit")) {
              System.exit(1);
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
          }
        }
      }
    });

    Thread getMsg = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (true) {

          String msgRead = "";

          try {

            msgRead = newClient.readMessage();

            System.out.println(msgRead);

          } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
          }
        }
      }
    });


    sendMsg.start();
    getMsg.start();
  }
}
```

I think the problem is here :

```
        // send to all except me
        for (ClientHandler client : MainServer.allClients){

          if (!client.clientName.equals(this.clientName)){
            client.out.println(this.clientName + ":" + recivedMsg);
            client.out.flush();
            break;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is straightforward: remove the `break` statement from the loop where you think the problem is.

This `break` statement causes the loop through all the `ClientHandler`s to stop as soon as it sends the message to one client. You don't want this: you want this loop to keep going and send the message to all clients other than the one that wrote the message.